# Start a condition when there s a specific text

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy the end of the column B and C in worksheet 1 
To column B and C in worksheet 2

I have this :
[image: Worksheet1]

and this is above : [image: above]

And here is the code

```js
'Copy of "Maintenances" in worksheet 2
                n = 58 'start to look row 58
                j = 2 'copy in row 2 in worksheet 2
                Sheets("1").Select 'select sheet 1 
             
                Do While Cells(n, 1) <> "x" 'do for each cells untill there is a "x" in column A                    
                    If Cells(n, 1) <> "x" Then 'if column A is empty, then :                    
                        Sheets("2").Cells(j, 2) = Sheets("1").Cells(n, 2) '                             
Sheets("2").Cells(j, 3) = Sheets("1").Cells(n, 3) '                             
j = j + 1
                    End If 'fin du if
                        n = n + 1
                Loop 'retourne au do while
```

I want to copy all row Under "maintenance" in worksheet 2, BUT the row of "maintenance" can change. the problem is not when the row is ending, but when it start. In my code, it copies column B and C between 58 and when there is a "x" in column 1. but I want that the copy start when in column B its "maintenance"

Comment: Can you include your data or the picture of it on your question?

Comment: Refer to your picture, are there any other data above `Cells(56,1)`?

Comment: y sir , and the pb is that i can delete row above, that means that "maintenance" will up, and i want to copy all Under "maintenance"

In my code, i copy all Under row 58... :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then you may replace `n = 58 'start to look row 58` with the following code to determine the value of variable `n` as a start row.

```
Dim WordToFind As String, FirstWord As String
Dim FindWord

WordToFind = "Maintenance"
    With Sheets("1").Range("A:C")
        Set FindWord = .Find(what:=WordToFind, SearchDirection:=xlNext)

        If Not FindWord Is Nothing Then
            FirstWord = FindWord.Row
            Do
                n = FindWord.Row + 1 'The value of n start from the row below "Maintenance"
                Exit Do
            Loop While Not FindWord Is Nothing And FindWord.Row <> FirstWord
        Else
            MsgBox "There is no word " & WordToFind
        Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
```

You can change the value `WordToFind` depending on a word or string you are looking for.

Comment: I want to copy all row Under "maintenance", BUT the row of "maintenance" can change.

the pb is not when the row is ending, but when it start.
In my code, it copies column B and C between 58 and when there is a "x" in column 1. but I want that the copy start when in column B its "maintenance"

Comment: @babou Truth be told, I find hard to understand what you want. Can you elaborate your question to convey your request? And what is **pb**? Also, where do you want to paste the copied data?

Comment: @babou Is "maintenance" in a merged cell? Are the above "maintenance" empty cells?

Comment: Maintenance is the text in cellule row 55, and no, above this its only full cells

Comment: @babou I know "maintenance" in row 55, but is it a merged cell? Can you give a full picture of above "maintenance"?

Comment: @babou I'm really tired right now & it's already late night here. If no one here helps you, I'll try my best to help you tomorrow. I hope you're fine with that.